# Undefined Symbols for architecture x86_64 Xcode Mac

Tags: c++, undefined, symbols

I need some help.
Recently I've tried to learn some programming, and had a couple of problems, but they've all been solved.
except for this one.
I know it has been answered many times, but I have never found a solution for my specific case.
I am using Xcode V. 4.5.2
Here is the program:

```
int add(int x, int y);

int main()

    using namespace std;
    cout << "3 + 4 + 5 = " << add(3, 4) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int add(int x, int y, int z)

    return x + y + z;
}
```

It gives me this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "add(int, int)",
>   referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>        (maybe you meant: __Z3addiii) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have no idea what to do.

I have been following this tutorial:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/17-forward-declarations/

the Fifth Program under Quiz is this one.

Thanks
Lemonizer

Answer (score 1):

Your forward declaration is `int add(int x, int y);` but your definition is `int add(int x, int y, int z)`. The first one has no `int z` but the second one does. They need to match 100%. The definition should probably be:

```
int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

That linker error is telling you "I don't know of any `add(int, int)` functions," which is appropriate, because there is no definition for any kind of `add(int, int)` function. There's only an `add(int, int, int)` function, which is, obviously, different.

Comment: I am aware of this, you see this is not the problem here.
The program is not supposed to work, it is for learning purposes that it does not, so that you can find the problem, (You did it :D) but this error is still not a part of it.

Thank you for your (Very!) quick answer, but unfortunately not the one I needed :(

Comment: @Lemonizer: Uh... what? According to your linker error, this is *exactly* what is wrong. Perhaps you meant for your forward declaration to be `int add(int x, int y);` and your function call to be `add(3, 4, 5)` then? There's a couple ways to fix the error, but my answer "The need to match 100%" is the exact solution. How you make them match 100% is up to you.

Comment: Hello again.
If you look at the link I later in the post, you can see that the author also mentions that it won't link, but he does not mention any ''Higher level errors'' this is not just a red !, it has its own page :S

Comment: Oh okay, guess I just overestimated the error then :P. Thank you for your quick answer. I will name my first program after you, if that is okay for you of course.

Long days and pleasant nights to you, Sir!
-Lemonizer